# Symfony Entites vs CollectionType

Tags: php, symfony

I have the following problem with Symfony. I made 3 entities: Customer, Cart, and CartItem. And what I want, is to display all the Products that are inside Cart (These are inside Cart Item), and to be able to change quantity on ever single one with some kind of form. The best way is to use CollectionType, but I get this error. Second thought I had, is that my entities are wrong?

```
The form's view data is expected to be a "App\Entity\Cart", but it is a "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection". You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection" to an instance of "App\Entity\Cart".
```

Cart Entity

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CartRepository::class)]
class Cart
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: User::class, inversedBy: 'carts')]
    private $customer;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'cart', targetEntity: CartItem::class)]
    private $cartItems;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cartItems = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCustomer(): ?User
    {
        return $this->customer;
    }

    public function setCustomer(?User $customer): self
    {
        $this->customer = $customer;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, CartItem>
     */
    public function getCartItems(): Collection
    {
        return $this->cartItems;
    }

    public function addCartItem(CartItem $cartItem): self
    {
        if (!$this->cartItems->contains($cartItem)) {
            $this->cartItems[] = $cartItem;
            $cartItem->setCart($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCartItem(CartItem $cartItem): self
    {
        if ($this->cartItems->removeElement($cartItem)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($cartItem->getCart() === $this) {
                $cartItem->setCart(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Cart Item Entity

```
<?php

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CartItemRepository::class)]
class CartItem
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual(1)
     */
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $quantity;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Product::class, inversedBy: 'cartItems')]
    private $product;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Cart::class, inversedBy: 'cartItems')]
    private $cart;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getQuantity(): ?int
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }

    public function setQuantity(int $quantity): self
    {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProduct(): ?Product
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    public function setProduct(?Product $product): self
    {
        $this->product = $product;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCart(): ?Cart
    {
        return $this->cart;
    }

    public function setCart(?Cart $cart): self
    {
        $this->cart = $cart;

        return $this;
    }



}
```

CartType

```
class CartType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('customer')
            ->add('cartitem', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => CartItemType::class,
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false]
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
                                   'data_class' => Cart::class,
                               ]);
    }
}
```

CartItemType

```
<?php

class CartItemType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('quantity')
            ->add('product')
            ->add('cart')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => CartItem::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

CartController

```
    #[Route('/', name: 'show_cart')]
    public function showCart(CartService $cartService, Request $request): Response
    {
        $cart = $cartService->getCartItem();
        $form = $this->createForm(CartType::class, $cart);


        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
           return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('app_home'));
        }


        return $this->render('cart/index.html.twig', [
            'cart' => $cart,
            'form' => $form
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Does `->getCartItem()` return a **Cart** entity or CartItem collection ?

Comment: @DylanKas Collection

Comment: Can you show us your CartService  file ?

Comment: You need to make CartService return the Cart object, not the items in it. If your CartService still looks the same as in your previous question, have it return `$userCart` instead of `$userCart->getCartItems();`

Comment: I did like you said @Marleen. But the thing is that I can't display Products, only the Quantity, which is inside Cart Item? As soon as I add products inside CartItemType, I get this error: `Object of class Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\Product could not be converted to string`

Comment: Add a __toString method to your Product entity

Comment: Maybe take a moment and update your posted code since it it pretty clear from the discussion and from `>add('cartitem', CollectionType::class,` that you were originally passing your $cartService object instead of a $cart object.  For testing purposes consider just new'ing a cart object and adding a few fake cart items just to get your form working.  And of course to properly show a Product you will eventually want to make a ProductType.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see you have two errors in your code:

In CartType you have used cartitem instead of cartitems. Symfony tried to use getCartItem, which is no method at all.

The CartType should look like following:

```
class CartType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('customer')
            ->add('cartitems', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => CartItemType::class,
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false]
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
                                   'data_class' => Cart::class,
                               ]);
    }
}
```

Also it seems like the data you throw into the form are no doctrine-entity matching the Cart-Entity. It seems like you give over an unparsed object to your form.

Answer (score 0):

```
$object->getCartItems();
```

The above will return the doctrine collection, as below image shows the entity was mapped to return the collection

[image: Refer this image, this will return collection]

try the below code, this will return the array of cart objects

```
$object->getCartItems()->getValues();
```

Comment: This will not help at all. The issue here is that CartType expect the entity passed to be a Cart, not a collection. I asked to see OP cart service to see if he could get a Cart instead. Passing an array to the form type will still not work since the data_class is set to a `Cart` entity.